# Calling webService using json gives error in Titanium but calling webService from terminal using curl works fine

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, appcelerator

Hi I am trying to call a webService in titanium using json.
That webService does not take any argument so i just have to call it.

here is my code:

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.setTimeout(10000);

xhr.open("POST","http://mytesturl.net/services/json/system.connect");  
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.send();
xhr.onerror = function() {

Titanium.API.info("some thing is wrong in calling");
};

xhr.onload = function() {

Titanium.API.info("The API response is " + this.responseText);
};
```

on the log i get this error :

```
The API response is {"#error":true,"#data":"Invalid method ","#response_code":405}
```

I thought the url is wrong but when i tried to call the same web services from my terminal i.e by using `curl` utility

```
curl --data method=system.connect http://mytesturl.net/services/json
```

i got the response what i needed..
what i am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing any payload to the server, but instead try to pass the method as a part of the URL. You'll need to add the `method=system.connect` as the `data` argument in the [send](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient.send-method.html) function call and change the URL to be same as in the curl request (http://mytesturl.net/services/json).

Comment: can you help me with some code..for now i tried `var data = {"method":"system.connect"}` and then `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));` am I correct

Comment: It depends whether the service needs the data in JSON format or not. Based on the curl example, I'd guess it expects the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. So you should try just passing `xhr.send("method=system.connect");`.

Comment: thanks you very much.. hope i could vote you up more than once...:)

Comment: Without `xhr.send("method=system.connect");` this work for me.